# Sets of Tag Taxonomies

Tags: discussion, tagging

Let's develop a set of tag taxonomies here to start looking at tag guidelines. One ontology per answer

Comment: can you provide a sample of the kind of tag ontology you infer? I think that the word ontology might be throwing myself off. I guess you mean hierarchy?

Comment: @drachenstern Hierarchy is also a valid word, and doesn't conflict with the philosophical uses of ontological. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/669/proposed-tag-synonyms/672#672 has a *remarkable* amount of discussion about this.

Comment: From an LIS (Library & Information Science) standpoint, what you're probably looking for are taxonomies.  See the 'Vocabulary Systems' section of a [handout from a poster I presented last month](http://vso1.nascom.nasa.gov/vso/misc/AGU_2010_vocab_handout.pdf)  It'd also be worth reading [Librariansplaining: The controlled vocabulary](http://scientopia.org/blogs/bookoftrogool/2010/08/05/librariansplaining-the-controlled-vocabulary/)

Answer (score 3):

- oracle

  - oracle-10g
  - oracle-11g

    - oracle-11g-r2
  - oracle-internals

    - dual (too specific?)
  - oracle-sql
  - pl/sql
  - sqlplus
  - cbo (? because not sure how it relates to other dbms)

    - statistics
    - explain-plan
  - security

    - fga
    - encryption

this post is CW so feel free to edit and add to this list as you come by other suggestions. Yes, even you.

Answer (score 3):

- sql-server
- sql-server-2000
- sql-server-2005
- sql-server-2008

  - sql-server-2008-r2
- sql-server-2011

  - sql-server-2011-ctp
  - sql-server-2011-r1
  - sql-server-2011-r2
- sql-server-management-studio   or ssms (*I think we should avoid abbreviations* )
- sql-server-tools

  - sql-server-profiler
  - sql-server-configuration

IMO There are two ways to tag sql server editions, `sql-server-edition-2008` or `sql-server-2008` & `express-edition`.
I like the second option, it looks more organized.

- edition

  - express-edition
  - standard-edition
  - enterprise-edition
  - web-edition
  - workgroup-edition
  - datacenter-edition

Comment: Some of your tags exceed the [max tag length](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/how-many-words-can-a-tag-contain/13274#13274) of 25 characters.