# What is the right thing to do to stop tag proliferation

Tags: support, tagging

For example this recent question uses the tag [oracle-11](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11) instead of [oracle-11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g). Should I just change the tag and delete [oracle-11](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11)?

Also should I change tags like [oracle-11xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11xe) to improve consistancy (eg to [oracle-11g-xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-xe) and [oracle-11g-r2-xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2-xe))

Answer (score 3):

> [When should the ‘rdbms’ tag be applied?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/when-should-the-rdbms-tag-be-applied)
>
> [Should there be dashes in Oracle-11g, Oracle-11g-R2, etc.?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209/should-there-be-dashes-in-oracle-11g-oracle-11g-r2-etc)

We should surely have [oracle11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle11g) over [oracle-11g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g) but yes [oracle-11](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11) is unlikely to help anyone.

> [Sets of Tag Taxonomies](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/sets-of-tag-taxonomies)

This also partly covered what you're asking here

> Also should I change tags like [oracle-11xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11xe) to improve consistency (eg to [oracle-11g-xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-xe) and [oracle-11g-r2-xe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2-xe))

Meaning that if the generic person "you" is going to search for a term, are you going to search for "oracle 11xe" on Google or are you going to search for "oracle 11g r2 xe"? We need to make the tags match what people would search for. (I don't use Oracle so I don't know) Our site's analytics show that "oracle xe" is a leading search term getting people to the site, so bear that in mind as well.

Comment: from the links you provide, I think you mean we should have oracle-11g over oracle11g

Comment: I ... uh .. probably.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a few questions with the mysql tag that was so generic (about SQL or doing backups for example) and non-mysql related that I just simply removed the tag and explained its removal. Maybe there should be a TagDeputy badge for having to screen question content against its proposed tags. There are still some questions lingering now that are tagged mysql and have no mysql nuances ever mentioned.

My answer may be a little out of context, but it is another form of tag proliferation (tagging incorrectly)